# non static variable cannot be referenced from static context?

Tags: java, variables, printing, byte

I'm new to java and I have been exploring the different variable types.  Right now I am trying to determine is printed when I add 1 to a byte variable of value 127 (the maximum value for a byte var).  This is what my code looks like:

```
public class vars {

    byte b = 127;
    byte c = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(b + c);


    }
}
```

and on my System.out.println line I get the error message that my non-static variables, b and c, cannot be referenced from a static context.  How should I fix this?  Is there a better way to do this project in general?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what instance variables are?

Comment: You might like to read through [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: One of solutions would be moving your variables to main method.

Comment: You need an `instance` of your class (i.e. `object`) to reference these variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this is code to use the member variable inside the main function you need the class object
 `vars v= new vars();`

```
  public class vars {

            byte b = 127;
            byte c = 1;

            public static void main(String[] args) {
        vars v=new vars();
            System.out.println((v.b + v.c));


            }
        }
```